# Mathematical proof for minimum number of clues in sudoku

Tags: combinatorics, sudoku

There must be at least [17 starting clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100/minimum-number-of-clues-for-a-sudoku-puzzle) in a sudoku to be univocally solved (brute force proof) but is there any mathematical (or if you want, more *elegant*) proof for this or research paper that tries to address it?

Comment: Not yet.$~~~~~$

Comment: That said, the original proof wasn't exactly brute force.  There are far too many grids possible to actually check each individually.  There were many optimizations made.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlyTq-xVkQE attempts to explain some of those optimizations in a friendly way, but reading the actual paper itself would provide the most details.